# ModelBinder does not update the session key

Tags: model-view-controller, session, object, modelbinder

I created a Website(it is poco object) model binder, that checks the sessions:
    public class WebsitesModelBinder:IModelBinder
    {
        private const string websitesSessionName = "SelectedSite";

```
    #region IModelBinder Members

    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        if (bindingContext.Model != null)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Invalid");

        Website site = (Website)controllerContext.HttpContext.Session[websitesSessionName];
        if (site == null)
        {
            site = new Website();
            controllerContext.HttpContext.Session[websitesSessionName] = site;
        }
        return site;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

In the global.asax file I registered the model binder for typeof website.
In my controller action, the action gets the website as a parameters and updates it such as:
    public ActionResult Websites(Website SelectedSite)
        {
            var sites = db.Websites.ToList();
            if (SelectedSite.ID == 0)
                SelectedSite = sites[0];
            ViewData["Selectedsite"] = SelectedSite;

```
        return View(sites);
    }
```

However model binder never updates the session 
Any ideas?

Comment: Your formatting is slightly off making the code harder to read.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old and may not be useful anymore, but I ran across this in a search of my own and wanted to answer from what I did. If you remove the if clause that throws an exception, then this should work. You are returning a reference, so this should update appropriately. Hopefully this helps for the future at least